# How to update a paginated list after a mutation?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a thread with a list of messages, which is fetched with a `GET_THREAD_MESSAGES` query. That query is paginated, and depending on if a user has seen the thread before or not might load the first page, last page or only the new messages. (i.e. any of `first/after/before/last` could be passed with any values)

```
thread(id: "asdf") {
  messageConnection(after: $after, first: $first, before: $before, last: $last) {
    edges {
      cursor
      node { ...messageInfo }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have a `sendMessage` mutation, which I call and then in the `update` method of that mutation I want to optimistically add that sent message to the threads messages for a nicer UX. Without pagination, I know I would do that something like:

```
const data = store.readQuery({
  query: GET_THREAD_MESSAGES,
  variables: { id: message.threadId }
})

data.messageConnection.edges.push(newMessageEdge);

store.writeQuery({
  query: GET_THREAD_MESSAGES,
  variables: { id: message.threadId },
  data,
})
```

Unfortunately, since I know have pagination the `store.readQuery` call throws an error saying “It can’t find the field `messageConnection` of that thread” because the field is now something like `messageConnection({ after: 'jfds1223asdhfl', first: 50, before: null, last: null })`. The [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/pagination.html#connection-directive) say that one should use the `@connection` directive in the query to work around that. I've tried to update the query to look something like this:

```
thread(id: "asdf") {
  messageConnection(...) @connection(key: "messageConnection") {
    edges {
      cursor
      node { ...messageInfo }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use that the optimistic update is returned and shown         correctly, but as soon as the server returns the actual message that was stored I get an error saying `"Missing field cursor in { node: { id: '...', timestamp: '...'"`, because obviously the message that the server returns is not a `MessageConnectionEdge`, it's just the node, and thusly doesn't have a cursor field.

How can I tell Apollo to only replace the node of the optimistic response, not the entire edge? Is there another way to work around the original issue maybe?

Comment: Can we see the mutation too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phew, I finally fixed this. The problem turned out not to be in the mutation at all, it was in the subscription that was running parallel for new messages in the thread. (facepalm)

**TL;DR: If you have a subscription on the same data as a mutation is changing, make sure to include the same fields in both update methods!**

The subscription method looked like this:

```
subscribeToNewMessages: () => {
  return props.data.subscribeToMore({
    document: subscribeToNewMessages,
    variables: {
      thread: props.ownProps.id,
    },
    updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
      const newMessage = subscriptionData.data.messageAdded;
      return Object.assign({}, prev, {
        ...prev,
        thread: {
          ...prev.thread,
          messageConnection: {
            ...prev.thread.messageConnection,
            edges: [
              ...prev.thread.messageConnection.edges,
              { node: newMessage, __typename: 'ThreadMessageEdge' },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
    },
  });
},
```

If you have good eyes, you'll immediately spot the issue: The inserted edge doesn't provide a cursor—which is exactly what Apollo Client is telling us in the warning! The fix was to add a cursor to the inserted edge:

```
{ node: newMessage, cursor: newMessage.id, __typename: 'ThreadMessageEdge' }
```

Hope this helps somebody else running into this warning, make sure to triple check both the subscription and the mutation `update` methods!

Comment: I appreciate the perfect answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I'll have a crack at this.

Without seeing the mutation I'll presume that it looks something like the following.

```
mutation NewMessage($message: String!, $threadId: ID!) {
  sendMessage(message: $message, threadId: $threadId) {
    ...messageInfo
  }
}
```

If that is the case, it's potentially unreliable to infer where in the connection the message should go. Since cursors are opaque strings we can't be certain that this message should indeed come after the latest message.

Instead I'd try something like the following.

```
mutation NewMessage(message: String!, threadId: ID!, $after: Cursor, first: Int) {

  sendMessage(message: $message, threadId: $threadId) {
    messageConnection(
      after: $after,
      first: $first,
      before: null,
      last: null
    ) @connection(key: "messageConnection") {
      edges {
        cursor
        node { ...messageInfo }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This connection should include the new message and any others that have been added since.

Here is the official documentation on the `@connection` directive: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#the-connection-directive

Comment: Thank you for so much for taking the time to take a stab at this.

The issue turned out to be in the subscription rather than the mutation, I've posted an explanation in full as a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279184/2115623

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for - it makes it so that the 'after', 'first', 'before', and 'last' variables are not considered as part of the cached query identifier. thank you!